# Which Arduino board would be sufficient for the following simulink project?

Tags: arduino-uno, memory-usage, solar

I'm trying to run a Fuzzy Logic MPPT Algorithm in Arduino UNO, [here's the Simulink File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b2aHGw1rrPcKOgMciU1zWIJqr5E1oU8Y?usp=sharing)

However when I try to upload the code, I get the following error

[image]

Is this project possible with UNO, if yes, what shall I do? Else which Arduino board would be suitable for this project?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot answer about your Simulink program (since this site is only about Arduino). But currently you are using 3 times the RAM an Uno has. You can try to optimize your Simulink program, though I doubt that you will be able to reduce the needed memory that much.

So you should switch to a board with significantly more RAM. There are many to choose from, with different RAM, flash, peripherals, pin numbers. Write down all your requirements and then look for a fitting board